# How to center GridView on the screen

Tags: android

How to center GridView on the screen.I have GridView with 4 items as 2 items per row. I try to center the GridView inside the Relative layout using padding in relative layout. But I developed application for multiple screens.So I think hardcoded padding is not good practice. How to center this Grid view on mulitple screens?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridrelativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="150dp"
    android:paddingRight="150dp"
    tools:context=".MainMenuActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F9F9F9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="50dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridrelativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="150dp"
    android:paddingRight="150dp"
    tools:context=".MainMenuActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="20dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="50dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true" 
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This updated code centers gridView on screen properly. But see,I hardcoded padding for left ad Right in Relative layout.As I want to support to multiple scrrens, I want to make this padding as dynamic using following code.But It not works.

```
RelativeLayout gridrelativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridrelativelayout);
        int pad=gridrelativelayout.getWidth()/3;
        gridrelativelayout.setPadding(pad, 0, pad, 0);
```

Comment: try android:layout_width="wrap_content" in GridView, same for layout_height.

Comment: my question is different.My above code works properly aligns on center.But I think it is not good practice.Because I need to support mulitple screens,How to set padding dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, you could do it programmatically or you could define values in dimensions.xml and use them like so: `android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"`. Then provide different versions of dimensions.xml for large, xlarge, etc.

Comment: Also I believe you don't need the RelativeLayout at all, make the GridView your top layout and set the padding there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply `RelativeLayout`

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and For `GridView`

```
android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
```

Comment: yes It fits vertically properly.But to center Horizontally I want to shrink width of gridview,other wise the grid view takes full width of screen

Comment: also make Gridview  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: no if add match_parent to GriView, the gridview match to parent(Relativelayout).So it not center on screen on vertical also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_centerInParent = "true"` for `GridView`. This surely works...

Comment: make android:layout_centerInParent = "true"  and gridView layout_height and layout_width = wrap_content. It makes center the Grid view only on Verticallu not horizontally. I want to shrink the width of grid view based on screen

Answer (score 0):

If want write best app to multiple screen devices, so you need read this:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

and it is very useful to you:

[Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: It is general document for supporting multiple screens.This question is specific about GrdView only

Answer (score 0):

Use

`android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"`

for GridView.